# Stop iPhone alerting me when I'm in a phone call

Tags: iphone

When I'm in a phone call, I still get alerts for emails and texts. The noise will play and, if the phone is on Speaker, it will vibrate -- often leading the person I'm talking to wonder what that weird noise was.

Surely there must be a way to silence the phone while you're talking on it. It's very distracting to have beepings going off right next to your ear!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like there is no setting to silence alerts during a call.

https://discussions.apple.com/message/16904276#16904276

> There's no phone setting to silence alerts during phone calls.  You
>   can suggest this to Apple: http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Answer (score 15):

Set `Settings > Sounds > Vibrate on Silent` to **OFF**; then while on the call you can flip the hardware switch to Silent. This will disable all sounds and vibration.

Comment: This is indeed what I ended up doing. Sounds counter-intuitive, but it works best for me. Thanks.

Comment: Good answer. A bit inconvenient as you won't really have a silent mode (with vibration), but great idea.

Comment: Now I have an Apple Watch I leave my phone permanently flicked to silent, so finally everything is perfect

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 15, you can accomplish this using [a custom Focus](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212608). I created a custom focus called “Telephone” that activates automatically while using the FaceTime or Phone apps.

Update: Unfortunately, iOS appears to treat the call in progress screen as a separate app from the Phone app itself, so this technique doesn’t quite do what we want.

Answer (score -3):

Quickest way to shut off text tone, or any other, is to tap volume up or down one click, this cancels tones. Also including when text tone wont stop after entering text from home screen (notifications) there's no need to play with the notifications setting all the time. You'll see others mention to reboot holding home and sleep simultaneously to do stop run-on tones, doesn't last or work most of the time.

Answer (score -6):

download a silent ringtone. Set your phone alerts to this ring tone. its the only  way.