# How to prevent iPhone from vibrating during calls?

Tags: iphone, ios, bug, call, vibrate

I can't figure out how to prevent my iPhone SE (iOS 10.2) from vibrating when messages arrive while I'm on a call (that is, it vibrates right into my ear). This happens regularly, and I'm sure it occurs with other models/software versions.

I cannot find any setting regulating this, therefore it looks like a major bug: it doesn't have any function and interferes with the normal phone usage.

Does anybody know if anything has been/is being done with respect to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to look in Settings > Sounds & Haptics.

In there you have various settings for Sound and Vibrate. Under the section "Sounds and Vibration Patterns" there's a "Text Tone" option. If you touch that, you have options for what happens when you receive a Text, both Sound and Haptics. One of the options for Haptics is "None"

Comment: Thank you, I believe that changes general settings for when text are received. What I'm looking for is for a way to disable the vibration only during calls, when I the vibrating device (the phone) is right at my ear

Comment: In that case, i believe this link may help:

http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/93590/stop-iphone-alerting-me-when-im-in-a-phone-call